# TypeScript/React - How to have function accept a generic component type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working with React/TypeScript right now. When writing unit tests, I'm big on re-usable setup logic. Things like rendering my React component with React Testing Library, which I have to do every single time, I want to have a function that does it for me. Basically I pass in my React component and a few other arguments, and it does all the setup logic. Here is what I have right now:

```
import React, { ComponentType } from 'react';
import { createMemoryHistory, MemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { createStore, RootState } from '../../../src/store';
import { EnhancedStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { render, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router } from 'react-router';

export interface RenderConfig<T> {
    component: ComponentType<T>;
    props?: T;
    reduxState?: Partial<RootState>;
}

export interface RenderResult {
    store: EnhancedStore<RootState>;
    history: MemoryHistory;
}

const renderComponent = async <T extends object>(config: RenderConfig<T>): Promise<RenderResult> => {
    const store = createStore(config.reduxState ?? {});
    const history = createMemoryHistory();
    const CompToRender = config.component;
    await waitFor(() =>
        render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router history={history}>
                    <CompToRender { ...(config.props ?? {}) } />
                </Router>
            </Provider>
        )
    );
    return {
        store,
        history
    };
};

export default renderComponent;
```

As you can see, the renderComponent function takes in a configuration argument. This contacts the component prop, which is ComponentType, as well as an optional Props argument. I want the props to be the same generic type as the ComponentTypes generic parameter.

When I do this, however, when I do  I get this error:

> TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.   '{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'.

I know that {} is the default type of ComponentType's generic type parameter. I just don't understand how to make this logic work.

Comment: Is using `component: ComponentType<any>` instead of `component: ComponentType<T>` as a property of the `RenderConfig` interface a solution that would work for you?

Comment: Because as far as I can see, that's how the `ComponentType` is used in the [official](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/v16/index.d.ts#L842) `React` types repo.

Comment: I mean, it's possible but I like the restriction that a generic parameter enforces.

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is that config.props is optional while the Component might require some props.

I managed to recreate the issue and then solve it by removing the optional type from props and removing the empty object in case there is no props.

[link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-hodgkin-3555m?file=/src/App.tsx)

The idea is that the T in ComponentType is very real, and might require some props to be passed to the component so you cannot make props optional or supply it with an empty object, because it may need props.